# How to check if a process is being hooked?

Tags: windows, process, hook, monitoring

Is their a a way to see if an application is being hooked? I want to be able to see if an application is being hooked, and if so maybe see what exactly is being hooked? I am not sure if this is possible but I would like to know. I am just looking for a prexisting application that does this to monitor some processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of different methods to hook functions. Some are easy to detect, some are harder.

[HookShark](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/HookShark) is capable of detecting quite a lot of the common hooking methods.

On thing that it cannot detect is hooking via vtable replacement in object instances. The intruder replaces the vtable pointer at the beginning of a dynamically allocated object with a pointer to his faked vtable where the functions to be hooked are redirected. No program from the outside can detect this because it cannot know what chunks of memory are vtable pointers.